Is there any way to download meta data of Einstein copilot action for replicating in another org?
I want to replicate an existing Einstein Copilot action for multiple Salesforce Orgs as my current setup is like a template and i wantto replicate this for my other clients as a solution? I don't see any proper documentation for this. Is there anyone having similar challenges?
